# mysql query with multiple left join takes lots of time to fetch data

Tags: mysql, datatable

I am using mysql select query to fetch rows from multiple tables to generate report.

As the no of rows increased it takes lots of time to fetch.

I found using left join makes query slow.

What alternative can be used to make query execute faster.

below is the query i am using. The result of query is a report which  gives count of patients depending on patients age and disease type.

For ex: disease is viral fever than for current month what is the count of patients between age of 0 to 15 male,0 to 15 female,16 to 45 male,16 to 45 female.

Query:

```
    SELECT 
        ds.disease_type as disease, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(pdm.visited_date, '%m-%Y'))='10-2019' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as patient_count, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN ((DATE_FORMAT(pdm.visited_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2020-03-01') THEN 1 else 0 end) as disease_morbidity_cumulative_no,
        SUM(case when ic.age BETWEEN 0 AND 15 AND ic.gender ='male' AND (DATE_FORMAT(pdm.visited_date, '%m-%Y'))='10-2019' then 1 else 0 end) as patient_age_count1_male, 
        SUM(case when ic.age BETWEEN 0 AND 15 AND ic.gender ='female' AND (DATE_FORMAT(pdm.visited_date, '%m-%Y'))='10-2019' then 1 else 0 end) as patient_age_count1_female, 
        SUM(case when ic.age BETWEEN 16 AND 45 AND ic.gender ='male' AND (DATE_FORMAT(pdm.visited_date, '%m-%Y'))='10-2019' then 1 else 0 end) as patient_age_count2_male, 
        SUM(case when ic.age BETWEEN 16 AND 45 AND ic.gender ='female' AND (DATE_FORMAT(pdm.visited_date, '%m-%Y'))='10-2019' then 1 else 0 end) as patient_age_count2_female, 
        SUM(case when ic.age >45 AND ic.gender='male' AND (DATE_FORMAT(pdm.visited_date, '%m-%Y'))='10-2019' then 1 else 0 end) as patient_age_count3_male, 
        SUM(case when ic.age >45 AND ic.gender='female' AND (DATE_FORMAT(pdm.visited_date, '%m-%Y'))='10-2019' then 1 else 0 end) as patient_age_count3_female 
    FROM (p_d_m pdm) 
        LEFT JOIN i_card ic ON ic.i_card_id = pdm.i_card_id
        LEFT JOIN disease ds ON ds.disease_id = pdm.disease_id 
        LEFT JOIN village v ON v.village_id = ic.village_id 
        LEFT JOIN phc p ON p.phc_id = v.phc_id 
        LEFT JOIN ind_card indc ON indc.ind_card_id = pdm.ind_card_id 
        LEFT JOIN block b ON b.block_id = p.block_id 
        LEFT JOIN sub_district s ON s.sub_district_id =b.sub_district_id 
        LEFT JOIN district d ON d.district_id = s.district_id 
    GROUP BY ds.disease_id
```

In what way i can change the query so that i can use all the joins and it does not not take much time.

Comment: Can you format your query in a manner we can read it??, It is imposible to read it right now

Comment: Can you format, please?

Comment: yes i have formatted it.please check

Comment: did you index your database properly?

Comment: No i did not use index

Comment: can you tell me how to use index.Because i tried but it does not work with this query

Comment: Why do you make so many JOINS if you don't use their info?, i think you can remove the joins from **LEFT JOIN village v** to **LEFT JOIN district d** because you are not using that information

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't put the result of the query in Database View then select * from the created View

Comment: Sorry i didnt get what u want to say.

Comment: I meant if you represent your query into MySQL view : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx   , then select * from that view